# Doctrine 2: Call to a member function format() on a non-object ... in DateTimeType.php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a `DateTime` field:

```
/**
 * Date time posted
 * @Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $dtPosted;
```

which is set to a default value by using a LifeCycleCallback

```
/**
 * @PrePersist
 */
function onPrePersist() {
    // set default date
    $this->dtPosted = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   format() on a non-object in
>   D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType.php
>   on line 46

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `date()` function returns a string. The `datetime` type works with `DateTime` objects. So either change the mapping type to `string` or use `DateTime` objects.

Comment: you are right. i shld use `date_create(date(...))` or `DateTime::__construct()`

Answer (score 28):

you could always use:

```
$this->updated = new \DateTime("now");
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

Comment: or put `use \DateTime;` at the top of the file and then `$this->updated = new DateTime("now");`

Answer (score 5):

Try and use your setCreated with annotations for @ORM\PrePersist and setUpdated with annotations for @ORM\PrePersist and @ORM\PreUpdate methods as opposed to prePersist and preUpdate methods...

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setCreated()
{
    $this->created = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setUpdated()
{
    $this->updated = new \DateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar problem, but with a `time` field, and this question and @romanb 's answer helped.

I was getting the following error, much like the one in the question.

```
Call to a member function format() on a non-object in 
... /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/TimeType.php on line 50
```

The solution was similar, for fields of the `time` datatype, Doctrine will accept an instance of PHP's `DateInterval`

```
$quizFixture1->setCompletionTime(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('743 seconds'));
```