# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in Doctrine

Tags: php, oop, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am using **date** as a **Data-Type** in DOCTRINE , but its giving me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php on line 53
```

Here is my code:

```
 /** 
 * private Date datePosted 
 * @Column(type="date")
 * @Assert\NotEmpty
 */
   private $datePosted ;
```

When i change type to string ,than it works fine. How can i fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2: Call to a member function format() on a non-object ... in DateTimeType.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378748/doctrine-2-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-a-non-object-in-datetimety)

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378748/doctrine-2-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-a-non-object-in-datetimety

Comment: Basically I didnt helped my, thats why I asked question, Can anyone provide me an answer ?

Comment: can you please post the code where you set the date field's value?

Answer (score 4):

Your annotation is wrong.

Try with this:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=false)
 */
 private $datePosted;
```

Hope this helps.

## EDIT

You have to update your getter and setter (change `YourEntityClass` for your Entity)

```
/**
 * Set datePosted
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datePosted
 * @return YourEntityClass
 */
public function setDatePosted($datePosted)
{
    $this->datePosted = $datePosted;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get datePosted
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDatePosted()
{
    return $this->datePosted;
}
```

Comment: Now its not inserting into database

Comment: If i set it to string than it inserts, but when i set it to Date ,than it doesnot inserts,

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Also, you have to update datePosted type in your db.

Comment: Can you show me your ControllerAction?

Comment: For future visitors: only use `@ORM\Column(type="date", ...)` if you don't care about hours and minutes, otherwise use `@ORM\Column(type="datetime", ...)`.