# Saving value in database having type time using doctrine 2 orm

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpexcel, zfdoctrine

I'm trying to save data using ZF2 Doctrine ORM Module using dynamic paramter as entity class name and initializing its object and saving data using dynamic values from excel sheet header,

```
$time = \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($rowData[0][$key], 'hh:mm:ss');
$obj->$setter(\DateInterval::createFromDateString($this->secondsToTime(strtotime($time))));
$this->orm->persist($obj);
$this->orm->flush();
```

> $this->secondsToTime(strtotime($time)) is returning time in format 4
>   hours 5 minutes 6 seconds

Field type is time, when I print $obj->getter(), it prints:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 4
    [i] => 5
    [s] => 6
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

But it doesn't save its value as 4:05:06 in database, it saves 00:00:00.
I tried answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378748/doctrine-2-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-a-non-object-in-datetimety)

Comment: What's type is the column? I think you should use a \Datetime php object instead of DateInterval and map him as a [doctrine time field type](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#time). Hope this help

Comment: its crazy, I used it before but there were errors, and now its working, i might have missed something

Comment: so you don't change your code?Now correctly save on db? What is the column type of the field?

Comment: @Matteo I mean I tried Datetime() earlier, but there was error and now I tried it again and its working perfectly. I might have missed something there and it made be believe that DateTime will not work and thats why I was trying something else, field type is time