# Fatal error: Call to a member function format()

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have the data contains this date  i want insert in Mysql by script Zend and Doctrine i get this message Error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\imprimvert\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType.php
>   on line 53
>
> 'dateCreation' => string '2013-10-24 10:01:03'
>   'firstDateAssignement' => string ''

how can i resolved that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378748/doctrine-2-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-a-non-object-in-datetimety)

Comment: Can you provide some code pls?

Comment: @Dakov i used in my controller $data ['dateCreation']     = $info ['date_creation']

Comment: @mariroza You should be using `DateTime` objects for datetime fields (the answer is in the link I posted) i.e `new \DateTime($data['dateCreation']);`.

Answer (score 2):

As @AlexP already suggested, you can use DateTime object:

```
<?php
$entity->setDateCreation(new \DateTime($data['dateCreation']));
```

Personally I am using [DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule) that provides a [Hydrator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md) to convert an array of data to an object, which is much more elegant:

```
<?php
$data['dateCreation'];

$hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($em);

$entity = $hydrator->hydrate($data, new Entity);

$em->persist($entity);
```

Comment: @Dakov i have always Error because some times i have dateCreation 2204 only and other time i have 24/02/2007 and other time i have this :2013-10-24 09:57:49  how can i resolved this issue Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you can use:
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-10-24 09:57:49');
or
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '24/02/2007');